# Suppressing OS Messages in Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm currently working on a C# app targeted for Windows Mobile 6 devices that will run in kiosk (being well aware that WinMob 6 [isn't the greatest platform for kiosk apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/raffael/archive/2008/03/01/supporting-kiosk-applications-on-windows-mobile-technically-achievable-vs-supported.aspx)).  I can move the taskbar off of the screen, but in certain conditions, the operating system will show a message/status box (for example, when ActiveSync starts up, it shows a dialog with the status of the connection process).  Is anyone aware of a way (either via code or registry settings) to suppress these sorts of messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can periodically check when those message boxes appear and close/destroy them using WM_CLOSE/DestroyWindow respectively.

Besides you can try [SureLock Studio](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/index.shtml) which handles these messages and many other situations to simulate kiosk mode.

Answer (score -1):

If your project has the budget consider looking at [Spb Kiosk Engine](http://www.spbsoftwarehouse.com/products/kioskengine/)